# Structuring Dependency Injection for a Class with Injected Services AND Data

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am using an IoC container that uses constructor injection (Castle Windsor, for example).  I have the following (example) class which manages a product...

```
public class ProductDataManager
{
    public ProductDataManager(Product product, IProductDataLoader productDataLoader)
    {
    }

    // a number of methods here that manage the products data in different ways...
}
```

It has a dependency on a Product which is only known by the classes consumer.  It also has a dependency on a product data loader service.  I define the implementer of this service in the IoC container.

**How do I define this class (ProductDataManager) in the IoC container (and/or the consuming class) so that the service dependency (IProductDataLoader) can be injected by the IoC container and the data dependency (Product) can be passed by the consuming class?**

Or is this a code smell?  If so, how can this be modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `TypedFactoryFacility` and do something like this (off the top of my head)... first, define an interface for your abstract factory:

```
public interface IProductDataManagerFactory
{
    ProductDataManager Create(Product product);
}
```

Register the factory like so:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(Component.For<IProductDataManagerFactory>().AsFactory());
```

Now services can depend on `IProductDataManagerFactory` and have Windsor invoke `container.Resolve` through an automagically implemented factory.

Note that the parameter name `product` in the method signature must correspond to the parameter name in the ctor of `ProductDataManager`.

Comment: If the factory is a simple new() then I'd say there's no need to even create an interface, there's nothing wrong with injecting a Func<Product, ProductDataManager>. You can even use a fancy facility to do it: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-1a-delegate.html

Comment: @Mark: While creating an `IXXXFactory` is more verbose, it is much more explicit and makes your code more understandable with factories. Using `Func<Product, ProductDataManager>` is a bit cryptic in my opinion.